# Como concatenar dados de um DataGridView e Salvar em um único campo do banco

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

Quero concatenar e salvar os campos de um datagridview, porém não sei como fazer isso.

O que eu Tenho:

método:

```
public void Gravar()
{
    string strQuery;
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO Prato";
    strQuery += (" VALUES(");
    strQuery += ("seq_prato.NEXTVAL,");
    strQuery += ("'" + _nome + "',");
    strQuery += ("'" + _porcao + "',");
    strQuery += ("'" + _preco + "',");
    strQuery += ("'" + _descricao + "',");
    strQuery += ("'1'");
    strQuery += (")");
    clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
    ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
}
```

Botão Salvar:

```
private void btnsalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if ((txtnome.Text == "") || (txtpreco.Text == "") || (txtingrediente.Text == "")) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Os Campos com * são de Preenchimento Obrigatórios!"); txtnome.Focus(); 
    }
    else
    {
        clnPrato Prato = new clnPrato();
        if (txtcod.Text != "")
        {
            Prato.cod = Convert.ToInt32(txtcod.Text);
            Prato.preco = Convert.ToInt32(txtpreco.Text);  
        }

        Prato.nome = txtnome.Text;
        Prato.porcao = comboporcao.Text;
        Prato.descricao = txtdescricao.Text;

        if (ObjOperacao == clnFuncoesGerais.Operacao.Inclusao)
        {
            Prato.Gravar();
            MessageBox.Show("Dados Gravados com Sucesso!", "Novo Produto " + txtnome.Text,
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        } 
    } 
}
```

DataGridView:

```
public void formataGridView()
{
    dgvprato.ColumnCount = 2;
    dgvprato.Columns[0].Name = "CÓDIGO";
    dgvprato.Columns[1].Name = "INGREDIENTES";         
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero concatenar a coluna CÓDIGO de todas as linhas e salvar na _descricao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas creio que você esteja tentando fazer assim:

Substituir isso: `strQuery += ("'1'");`

por isso: `strQuery += (_código.ToString());`