# Selecionando todas as Rows de um DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para selecionar todas as `Rows` de um `DataGridView`.

Código que eu tenho:

```
DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método [`DataGridView.SelectAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectall.aspx) para selecionar todas as linhas:

```
dataGridView1.SelectAll();
```

Para selecionar as linhas de uma coluna específica, faça assim, por exemplo no `click` de um botão:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

    for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        dataGridView1[0, i].Selected = true; // "0" Indica a primeira coluna
}
```

Comment: Tem como adaptar ali no meu? No caso eu quero as Cells[0] de todas as linhas.

Comment: Mas esse código não retorna nada, somente limpa a seleção, percorre o `dataGrid` e seleciona as linhas baseado na coluna. Em todo caso, se você quiser abrir uma nova pergunta e explicar o que pretende fazer, talvez seja possível chegar à uma solução.

Comment: @enzo Mas já não foi respondido [**aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159126/como-concatenar-dados-de-um-datagridview-e-salvar-em-um-%c3%banico-campo-do-banco) e [**aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159112/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-salvar-v%c3%a1rios-valores-em-um-%c3%banico-campo-do-banco)? (*se possível apague os comments anteriores!*)

Comment: Sim, não ficou bem do jeito que eu queria, mas vou deixar assim mesmo .valeu.